# Derive an equation of the form Y = MX + C from $y\:=\:px^2+q\sqrt{x}$, where p and q are constants

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, logarithms

Hello and Good day to you all. I have been trying to linearize the following equation to the form Y = MX + C in order to plot a straight a line graph with a given set of x and y values. I have arrived at an answer but I am not totally sure.
The following is my answer:

$y\:=\:px^2+q\sqrt{x}$ where p and q are constant

Squaring both sides of the equation gives =>

$y^2\:=\:p^2x^4+q^2x$

Applying Natural Log(ln) to both sides of the equation gives

$\ln \left(y^2\right)\:=\:\ln \left(p^2x^4\right)\:+\:\ln \left(q^2x\right)$

=> $2\ln \left(y\right)\:=2\ln \left(p\right)\:+4\ln \left(x\right)\:+\:2\ln \left(q\right)+\ln \left(x\right)$

=> $2\ln \left(y\right)\:=2\ln \left(p\right)+\:2\ln \left(q\right)+5\ln \left(x\right)$

=> $2\ln \left(y\right)\:=5\ln \left(x\right)\:+\ln \left(p^2q^2\right)$

Is this answer correct and is this the final answer?

Thank you

Comment: You squared the right side incorrectly. $(a+b)^2 \ne a^2 + b^2$. Then $\ln(c+d) \ne \ln(c) + \ln(d)$. There is no way to linearize this.

Comment: @EthanBolker, I just noticed that. I will redo it

Comment: **If $x$ is large however** such that $px^2>> q\sqrt{x}$ then perhaps $y=px^2$ is a good approximation, this simplified equation $y=px^2$, which again, is an approximation and is not exact, can be linearized to $\ln(y) = 2 \ln(x) + \ln(p)$.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not in general have that

$$\log(r + s) = \log(r) + \log(s),$$

which implies that the math equation following

*Applying Natural Log(ln) to both sides of the equation gives*

is invalid.

---

The problem may be shortcutted by noticing that when $x = 0$, that $y = 0.$

Therefore, in searching for $M,C$ to satisfy

$$y = Mx + C, $$

$C$ must equal $0$.

This means the problem is reducing to solving for $M$ so that $M$ satisfies:

$$Mx = Px^2 + q\sqrt{x}. \tag1 $$

Without loss of generality, $x$ may be assumed to not equal $0$, since when $x = 0,$ any value for $M$ will fit.

Dividing both sides of (1) above, by $x$ gives

$$M = px + \frac{q}{\sqrt{x}}. \tag2 $$

No constant $M$ can satisfy (2) above, because the RHS of (2) above will vary, as $x$ varies.

Therefore, there is no solution.